# Change the value which follows a specific string in a txt file

Tags: python, regex

This sounds like a common problem to solve, but i never found a proper solution.
I have a txt file with look like:

```
variable_name1 = '1'
variable_name2 = '0'
```

etc.

Hence I want to write a Python script which would find a line in the txt file which contrains `variable_name1`(input of the function) and would set variable equal to `x` (which is also an input).
So far I have tried:

```
line = "Cats = '2'"
matchObj = re.match( r'Cats = (.*)', line)
print("matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1))
k=(matchObj.group(1))
print(k)
```

However I want *Cats* to be an input. And I want it to find it in from a txt file with contains more than 1 line.

Comment: @Bach - Dont remove Python word in question heading...

Comment: @user1153551 See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/204922).

Comment: @user1153551 I think you should really read the link I gave you above and I won't reply anymore here because it's really not constructive to the question to do so. All the arguments for not putting tags in titles are mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using list formatting:

## Simple example:

```
>>> word = 'This'
>>> print('{} is string formatting'.format(word))
This is string formatting
```

## Your code specifically:

```
line = "Cats = '2'"
word = str(input('Enter keyword: '))

matched = re.match('{} = (.*)'.format(word), line).group(0)
print(matched)

>>> python script.py
Enter keyword: Cats
Cats = '2'

>>> word = 'Dogs'
>>> print(re.match('{} = (.*)'.format(word), "Dogs = '3'").group(0))
Dogs = '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just assign your variable name to a variable and then include that in your regex like this example:

```
line = "Cats = '2'"
variable_name = "Cats"

import re
f = re.findall(word+" = '(.*)'", line)
print f
```

output:

```
['2']
```

hope this helps.